# add http:// to input if not present on blur

Tags: angularjs

For all input fields with the type of url (input[type=url]), on blur I wish to check if the value of an input contains http:// or https:// and if it does not to add http:// to the beginning of the user inputted value. Similar to the below jquery:

```
$('.txtUrl').blur(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().match(/^http/) || $(this).val().match(/^https/)) {
        $.noop()
    }
    else {
        // get value from field
        var cur_val = $(this).val(); 
        // do with cur_val
        $(this).val('http://' + cur_val);
    }        

});
```

How do I do this the angular way?

Comment: Don't. Instead, do it on save. But, if you must, use the ngchange event.

Comment: simply use directive to do DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the same functionality using angular directive. 
Define `ng-model` that will take care of `ng-model` value.

**Markup**

```
<input type="url" my-directive ng-model="myUrl"/>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel)
            element.on('blur', function(e) {
                var value = ctrl.$modelValue; //ngModel Value
                if (value.match(/^http/) || value.match(/^https/)) {
                    angular.noop()
                } else {
                    // assign value to $modelValue
                    model.assign(scope, 'http://' + value);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This could help you, Thanks.